# How can I combine my three 2D tensors into a single 3D tensor in tensor flow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

Hello I am a newbie with the tensorflow and currently, I am working with colour Images and it's PCAS.

I have extracted PCAS in a form of "Red","Green" and "Blue" and also computed the weights which are associated with "Red","Green" and "Blue" components.

After doing the all the above stuff I want to combine all three 2D matrices into the single 3D matrix.

For a tensorflow it would be a 3D tensor.

`def multi(h0,ppca,mu,i,scope=None):`

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope or"multi"):
        return tf.matmul(ppca[:,:,0],h0[i,:,:,0]) + tf.reshape(mu[:,0],[4096,1]) , tf.matmul(ppca[:,:,1],h0[i,:,:,1]) + tf.reshape(mu[:,1],[4096,1]) ,tf.matmul(ppca[:,:,2],h0[i,:,:,2]) + tf.reshape(mu[:,2],[4096,1])
```

So from the above function, I will get all three different 2D tensors and  want to combine those 2D tensors to single 3D tensor which has dimensions [4096,1,3]

How can I do that? 
any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concat them like this:

```
three_d_image = tf.concat(0, [[r], [g], [b]])
```

This tells tensorflow to concat them along the `x` dimension and treat each tensor as a matrix.

Doing the same without the additional brackets around the r,g,b tensors will try to concat them to one large 2D matrix

Comment: Thanks Dotan sir, but please do one minor correction in answer. It's three_d_image = tf.concat([[r], [g], [b]],0) for newer version of tensorflow 1.0

Comment: Actually, for what is asked, you will not concatenate on dimension 0 as it would output a tensor of shape [3, 4096,1], and using concat like this is not appropriate. I would rather do  three_d_image = tf.stack([r,g,b], 2)

Comment: Right, can you tell me the difference of tf.stack([r,g,b], 2) , tf.stack([r,g,b], 3) and tf.stack([r,g,b], 1)

Comment: the axis argument change which place your new dimension will take, and therefore, the shape of your tensor : for axis 0 the shape will be [3,4096,1], for 1 it will be [4096, 3, 1], and for 2 it will be [4096, 1, 3]. Here 3 would raise an exception as it has no meaning.

Answer (score 3):

A clean, easy way to do it is using the tf.stack operation (tf.pack in older versions of tensorflow), it concatenats all tensors along a new dimension. If you want your new dimension to be after all previous, you need to set the axis argument to the number of dimensions of your tensors.

```
    three_d_image = tf.stack([r,g,b], axis=2)
```

Comment: This is the better answer I think. But it should be axis=0 (which is default)

Comment: Thanks, for your remark, in the question he says that he wants a final shape of  [4096,1,3], so axis=2 is required.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions is that you can add one more empty dimension to your 2Ds so you will have 3 matrices of 3D dimension [4096,1,1] then you can concat these 3 matrices by axis 2 `tf.concat(2,matrices)` gives you [4096,1,3]

the second solution can be concat of axis 1, `tf.concat(1,matrices)` then reshape it to 3D